# Loop Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, while-loop

If the **newWord** is **null** ,it should not go in the loop,but why does it go inside the loop and gives **java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
newWord = "abcd";
while(!newWord.equals(null))
{
    try {
    newWord = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    catch(NullPointerException p)
    {

    }
}
```

It gives the stacktrace but i have not used **printStackTrace()** anywhere

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`newWord` itself is null. When an object is null, you can't call any methods on it as the object is not defined. As `.equals` is a method, you are getting an exception.  Try this instead:

```
newWord != null
```

This is a problem easily solved by debugger. Learning to use a debugger is frustrating (as is learning any new tool,) but it will save you many hours of pain. It is your friend.

Comment: @JohnSnow I'm glad! Remember to upvote anyone who helped. It helps our fragile egos :-) Also accept the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

how about simply

```
    while(newWord!=null)
```

Think about it, If newWorld is null, what happens when you call methods on it ?

Comment: Don't know, +1 to fight the haters.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't go into the loop because

```
newWOrd.equals(null)
```

will throw an NPE if it is null

What you meant was

```
newWord != null
```

You can see this behaviour if you use a debugger, or look at the line in your stack trace where it is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
!newWord.equals(null)
```

is your problem.

Use `newWord != null`

Comment: String's equals method is never entered as anObject in this case is null. The line `if(anObject instanceof String)` is fine by itself if anObject is null.

Comment: Ah, much better. Good job, +1

Answer (score 0):

You only check if "newWord" is null, never if "br" has anything left reading from.

Something like:

while(br.hasNext());

Answer (score 0):

the NullPointerException you are getting is because of `while(!newWord.equals(null))` and it is not caught because try , catch were used after this code.

If you want to suppress this exception to then put that `while(!newWord.equals(null))` in try-catch block.

Comment: Suppressing the exception is not the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The argument for String.equal should not be null and explicitly null is passed so is the exception. Use compound expression to check for empty string and special null.

It tried to evaluate the expression before entering loop, soon the expression is encountered `!newWord.equals(null)`, because of `newWord` being null an exception were thrown.

Comment: Passing null into `String.equals` is fine. The problem is `newWord` is null.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid null exception in most of the cases (inside conditional expressions) I advise you to use Yoda conditions:

```
if(null != value)
```

Furthemore, this apply to every condition between a variable and a constant:

```
if(MY_CONSTANT_STRING.equals(myVariableString))
```